# How to show items on Appbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, mobile

Trying to create items on a toolbar but they are not showing up. I have posted all my necessary code below. My toolbar shows correctly, however my items do not show and I do not know why. Any help would be appreciated

Main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_left"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_right"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

App_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/readerBar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:id="@+id/include" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.readerBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is the result I get:

[image: Image of result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code + menu setup looks good, I think the menu items aren't showing up because this part: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` fails (toolbar == null); because it's inside a layout include with ID.

When you remove `android:id="@+id/include"` the toolbar should get setup correctly and show the items.

Comment: It still does not show the items.unfortunately

Comment: I created a clean project in Android Studio 4.1.1 just now with your code, and my removal suggestion. All seems to work, only thing I did in the newly created project was to change the theme so it isn't including a Toolbar by default (changed ".DarkActionBar" to ".NoActionBar"). Maybe you can try the same and see if you get it to work this way?

Answer (score 1):

`Appbar` has limitations set by google that make it difficult to work.
So I have another suggestion for you,
You can replace your `Appbar` with a `RelativeLayout` or any parent layout you want.

It's better because you can customize it any way you want.
For example, you can add your Icon by `imageView` and then ser listener for them and control them.

And if you want your parent height is the same with `Appbar` set your layout height like this.

`android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`